# Django ManyToManyField initializes with all objects by default

Tags: django, initialization, manytomanyfield, m2m

I have 2 classes, Player and Game. Players can own multiple games, so we are using a m2m relation inside the Player model:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    store_user = models.OneToOnefield(User, unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    games = models.ManyToManyField(Game)
    isDeveloper = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
```

My problem is, when a new Player registers, for some reason they get all of the game objects that have been added to the database. How can I make it so the new player would initially have no games?

User signup from views.py:

```
def signup(request):
  if request.user.is_authenticated:
      return render(request, 'home.html')
  else:
      if request.method == 'POST':
          user = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
          if user.is_valid():
              user.save()
              temp_user = User.objects.get(username=user.cleaned_data.get('username'))
              s_user = Player(store_user=temp_user, isDeveloper=user.cleaned_data.get('developer'))
              s_user.save()
              return redirect('login')
      else:
          user = UserCreateForm()
      return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': user})
```

Comment: please, add some more code from views.py.

Comment: @SadmanSobhan I have added the user signup method.

Comment: What makes you think the player gets all games in the database? You haven't written any code that makes that happen. In the admin, the selection box simply shows all the ones that are *available* to be selected; you actually have to select some (by clicking on them) to add them to teh player.

Answer (score 0):

For many to many field you need to use intermediate table. For details follow https://medium.com/@adriennedomingus/django-adding-an-intermediate-model-to-a-manytomany-field-without-one-493ee52ba4a5

`class Player(models.Model):
    games = models.ManyToManyField(Game)`

`class GamePlayer(models.Model):
    players = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    games = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have corrected the problem. I will mark it as an answer once I can confirm it.

Comment: No, you do *not* need an intermediate table. This answer is simply wrong.